# How to make web form post directly to Google Sheets without authentication page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, cors

## Background

I simply want to create a [landing page](http://tivly.lobolabshq.com/) that has a form that saves visitors email address in a Google Sheet.

I found this useful [post](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) that has a google app script that does the work. I followed the instructions (on my localhost) and here is the request code:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/my_app_script_id/exec",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});
```

But when I click on submit I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://script.google.com/macros/s/my_app_script_id/exec.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Which is kind of weird, considering that I have already published the app to be accessible from everyone as depicted here:

[image]

Fair enough, I need to [use CORS to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors).

## Problem

The instructions above require that users authenticate themselves, so this is what a user flow would look like on my landing page:

`given` user adds email in text field
`when` user clicks on **get started** button
`then`
**expected**
the form should submit just fine
**actual**
a Google Authentication screen shows up, and asks people to authorize the app

## Question

How can I make the web form run the Google App script without?

## Update

Interestingly, I tested the same script on the [blog post](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) and it works fine, but if I copy the url of the script there `https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzV--xTooSkBLufMs4AnrCTdwZxVNtycTE4JNtaCze2UijXAg8/exec"` and call it from *my* webservice, I get the same CORS error message.

So this is proof that the script can't just be called by anyone, it must be whitelisted somehow. How can I do that?

## Update 2

The author of the blog article [implied](https://twitter.com/mhawksey/status/840245810646417409) that I should be using https, working on setting that up.

## Update 3

I'm using JSONP right now, but somehow the way the google app script interprets the JSONP data is weird.

So as instructed by [Spencer Easton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3014703/spencer-easton) I'm calling it like so:

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK...g8/exec?data=" + serializedData +"&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, successCallBack).fail(failCallback)
```

however I keep on getting undefined,

[image]

I tried to debug my Google App script code using instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871475/766570) like so:

```
function fakeGet() {
  var eventObject = 
    {
      "parameter": {
        "email": "hindi",
        "callback": "fakecallback"
      }
    }
  doGet(eventObject);
}
```

This code worked perfectly and updated the spreadsheet as expected. So what am I missing here? How is Google App script exactly interpreting the jsonp data?

Comment: Did you remember to publish the script as as web app with "access all" (as stated in the comments to the script) ? I use a similiar solution that works flawlessy without authentication (albeit possibly not from localhost, you might try a webserver).

Comment: as a matter of fact i did.. forgot to add that in the question though.. that's what made that error message all confusing to me

Comment: And just to make sure (sorry), you did replace "my_app_script_id" with your actual id ?

Comment: of course, i just hid it for security.. updated question with screenshot

Comment: I'll try deploying the code on a webserver and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @EikePierstorff just deployed to webserver, same error. Are you sure your permissions match mine above?

Comment: @EikePierstorff please see update to question

Comment: TL:DR Don't return JSON or use JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning JSON you have to use JSONP.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages
>   http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/jsonpnotp

For you it would roughly look like:

postToSheet.js

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK...g8/exec?data=" + serializedData +"&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, successCallBack).fail(failCallback)
```

code.gs

```
...
 // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
var callback = e.parameter.callback; // required for JSONP
...
return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(callback+'('+ JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow})+')')
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
```

Comment: Jsonp has many limitations.. and the example on the blog used JSON just fine

Comment: I tried your idea.. it's adding undefined values to the spreadsheet instead of the actual email.. i'm trying to debug the google app script to see whta's going on

Comment: I tried your method, but it seems that google app script interprets jsonp data in an unexpected way.. please see my update 3

Comment: it worked, but i had to remove the data part.. so like this: `var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/sheet_id/exec?" + serializedData +"    &callback=?";`