# Where can i see the analytics of an Google App Script Deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, analytics

I created a small app on top of a spreadsheet (with GAS and HTML, CSS) and I deployed it.
Users can access to it without having to enter in the spreadsheet.

It works really well but i'm not able to see even the basic analytics (for eg. the number of viewers)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project overview page. In the Google Apps Script web IDE, on the lefmost sidepanel click on Overview.

[image]

Also, if you have starred your project, go to https://script.google.com/home/starred

Rather than "viewers" you will see "users". If you have set your web-app as execute as you by anyone even anonymous, you will see only one user, you, as this page show the users that exectuted the scripts like the `doGet` function and the server-side functions called through `google.script.run`.

Note: https://script.google.com keep execution logs for the last 7 days. If you need to keep the logs longer you have to use another place to keep these logs, i.e. Cloud Logging (requires a Google Cloud standard project), Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Related

- [Effective way to debug a Google Apps Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11493643/1595451)

Comment: That's great. Only problem I can see the active "users" over the last 7 days. It is possible to increase this time frame?